# jasypt-spring-boot encrypt value not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, jasypt

I want to do encryption for some sensitive data in application.properties file of spring boot application.
I used,

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
    </plugin>
```

> Maven vertion - 3.8.1.jar

I have try different scenarios
Using command,

> mvn jasypt:encrypt-value -Djasypt.encryptor.password="password"
> -Djasypt.plugin.value="thimira"

error - [image]

- mvn jasypt:encrypt-value "-Djasypt.encryptor.password=password"
  "-Djasypt.plugin.value=thimira"

error - [image]

also used @EnableEncryptableProperties in main method. How could I fix this issue.

Comment: Do not use images for text, logs and code